# How to Convert these3 SQL queries into One?

Tags: sql

Is there anyway i can convert the below 3 sql queries into a single query ?

```
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type) Select FirstName,Age,'Type1' FROM Table2 where Type='SK'
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type) Select FirstName,Age,'Type23' FROM Table2 where Type='JK'
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type) Select FirstName,45,'Type64' FROM Table2 where Type='YP'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type) 
Select FirstName,Age,'Type1' FROM Table2 where Type='SK'
union all
Select FirstName,Age,'Type23' FROM Table2 where Type='JK'
union all
Select FirstName,45,'Type64' FROM Table2 where Type='YP'
```

Comment: Simplicity in design--by far the best answer of the posted answers.

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type) 
Select FirstName, 
       CASE WHEN Type = 'YP' THEN 45 ELSE Age END, 
       CASE WHEN Type = 'SK' THEN 'Type1' etc.
FROM Table2 
where Type in ('SK', 'JK', 'YP')
```

EDIT:

It depends here how many types there are. Maybe another table that stores the types and the correpsonding texts ('Type' etc.) would be better instead of a huge case. And same thing for the age.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   Insert table1(Name,Age,Type)
    Select FirstName, 
         Case Type When 'YP' Then 45 Else Age End,
         'Type' + Case Type 
                    When 'SK' Then '1'
                    When 'JK' Then '23'
                    When 'YP' Then '64' End
    From Table2
    Where Type In ('SK', 'JK', 'YP')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
insert into table1(Name,Age,Type)  

(Select FirstName,

  (case when type='YP' then
    45
  else
    age
  end) age,

  (case when type='SK' then
    'Type1'
  when type='JK' then
    'Type23'
  when type='YP' then
    'Type64'
  end) type
 FROM Table2 where Type in ('SK','JK','YP'))
```